# Is there a way to get an animated shape in Python's turtle?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to use the `turtle.shape()` with a gif image.

So I'm wondering if there is anyway to make this image an animated image instead of a still image. I'm trying to do it without using a loop, because that breaks what I'm trying to do. I also need to use the turtle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I found the answer.

I just needed to do a repeat loop and have the turtle.onkey() above it for it to work. :D

EDIT
This is what I used:

```
while animOn == True:
    turtle.shape(shapename1)
    time.sleep(time between next image)
    turtle.shape(shapename2)
    if animOn == False:
        break
```

You can have multiple animations at once, but I've found that it can only work if all animations are in the same loop, so you may have to organise them if you intend to have more than 1 running at once.

Comment: An MCVE of your solution would be of interest to others as simply registering an animated GIF as a turtle cursor doesn't seem to be sufficient.

Comment: Ok I'll add to this